# Select option value based on a string array in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have a for loop in my View which generates a Dropdownlist. This loop iterates utill the value of an array SessionData.ddlCondition.Length

```
for(int i = 0; i < SessionData.ddlCondition.Length; i++)
            {
                <select class="ddlList">
                    <option value="Uwi" datatype="String">Uwi</option>
                    <option value="Uwi2" datatype="String">Uwi2</option>
                    <option value="UwiType" datatype="Decimal">UwiType</option>
                    <option value="Uwi2Type" datatype="Decimal">Uwi2Type</option>
                    <option value="Name" datatype="String">Name</option>
                    <option value="SiteType" datatype="Decimal">SiteType</option>
                    <option value="EffectiveDate" datatype="Date">EffectiveDate</option>
                    <option value="EffectiveEndDate" datatype="Date">EffectiveEndDate</option>
                    <option value="OilAllocationPlace" datatype="Decimal">OilAllocationPlace</option>
                    <option value="GasAllocationPlace" datatype="Decimal">GasAllocationPlace</option>
                    <option value="WaterAllocationPlace" datatype="Decimal">WaterAllocationPlace</option>
                    <option value="CondyAlloationPlace" datatype="Decimal">CondyAlloationPlace</option>

                    <option value="AffectsParentOilProd" datatype="Decimal">AffectsParentOilProd</option>
                    <option value="AffectsParentWaterProd" datatype="Decimal">AffectsParentWaterProd</option>
                    <option value="AffectsParentGasProd" datatype="Decimal">AffectsParentGasProd</option>
                    <option value="AffectsParentCondyProd" datatype="Decimal">AffectsParentCondyProd</option>   
                    <option value="OilConnectionParent" datatype="Decimal">OilConnectionParent</option>
                    <option value="GasConnectionParent" datatype="Decimal">GasConnectionParent</option>
                    <option value="WaterConnectionParent" datatype="Decimal">WaterConnectionParent</option>
                    <option value="CondyConnectionParent" datatype="Decimal">CondyConnectionParent</option>

                    <option value="OilSatellite" datatype="Decimal">OilSatellite</option>
                    <option value="GasSatellite" datatype="Decimal">GasSatellite</option>
                    <option value="WaterSatellite" datatype="Decimal">WaterSatellite</option>
                    <option value="CondySatellite" datatype="Decimal">CondySatellite</option>

                    <option value="GOR" datatype="Decimal">GOR</option>
                    <option value="UseGor" datatype="Boolean">UseGor</option>
                    <option value="Notes" datatype="String">Notes</option>

                    <option value="OpFlag" datatype="Decimal">OpFlag</option>
                </select>
            }
```

The ddlCondition is declared as string[] ddlCondition. This stores the selected values from this dropdownlist int the Controller.

```
string[0] =  "Uwi"
string[1] =  "Uw2"
string[2] = "UwiType"
string[3] = "Uwi2Type"
................
................
```

Now, I want to select the option in my View for string[2]. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the following change to your view, i.e. give a name to your drop down

```
 var name = "ddlCondition[" + @i.ToString() + "]";
 <select class="ddlList" name='@name'>
```

and in your action

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string []ddlCondition)
```

This way, you'll get the posted values in `ddlCondition` and you can access values of respective dropdowns using `ddlCondition[2]` and so on